# Any way to get the column causing a com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-server-2005, jdbc

We have a webapp that uses hibernate to persist data to a sql server 2005 instance.

On occasional we get a `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.`

While we can get the insert query, and then compare by hand to the column definition in the database to see which column is too small, this is slow and error prone. Is there a way to automatically get the Table/Column that has the problem from this exception?

I've looked around Google and SO for a solution, so I'll understand if the answer is "no, you cannot get that information", but I figured it didn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score -2):

This error can occur, when You try to put into table column, bigger data than You can, for example:

your column setting is varchar(10) and you try put "some data more length than 10"

Then you get error like: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.`

Check input data and Your settings.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of that, as I stated in the OP. However, this doesn't answer the question of which column it is without hand checking the data being inserted, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.